# Assign one property to child of a class

Tags: css

I've a class named `entry` that contains different parts of post article of my web site. Something like below:

```
<div class="entry">
 <div id="author-box-single">
  <div class="author-box">
   <div class="at-img">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <h1></h1>
 <p></p>
 <h2></h2>
</div> <!-- End of entry -->
```

As you see it contains many `div`s and headlines and etc. How can I assign one property, for example `padding-right: 10px` to all `child`s of `entry`?

Comment: direct child or nested children also?

Comment: @RahulArora I like to know both of the methods but I need nested children too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` sign means everything. `>` means direct children. For example:

```
.entry > * {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

will assign property to every direct child.

```
.entry  * {
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```

will assign property to everything inside it.

You can use div instead of `*`

```
.entry > div {
 padding-right: 10px;
}
```

will assign to all direct `<div>` children.

Comment: But I have to add `.entry > p` too, because it didn't act on `p`.

Comment: @ata What did you write? It didn't act on `p` when you wrote with `.entry > *`

Comment: I wrote `.entry *`

Comment: It is beacuse of css attribute specificity. You can google it or may this link will help you. https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2):

For direct child for div having class `entry`, you can use CSS combinators

[CSS combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

```
div.entry > div{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

For all the divs (even nested) under div having class `entry`

```
div.entry div{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```